# Flutter app crashes on /lib/arm64 - couldn't find "libflutter.so"

Tags: android, flutter, crashlytics

I recently released my application on the Play Store and I've been receiving a large number of crash reports as below.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mynewsapp/com.mynewsapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mynewsapp-gPJd8MyNcgdyJYrEzcZOUw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mynewsapp-gPJd8MyNcgdyJYrEzcZOUw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
```

We know flutter doesn't support x86 on aab but this is happening from lib/arm64 couldn't find "libflutter.so". Hence i extracted the aab file which i released and it has only these folders under lib arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, and x86_64.

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this? Why arm64 folder not there? And who are those users?

[image]

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Which SDK version are you on (check your pubspec.yaml for the SDK:). I've been having these issues on my apps for a long time as well, but now noticed I was still running on version 2 of the SDK. As mentioned in comments below, this might've been in later version (3.7). I will try upgrading now.

Comment: Any updates on this? I still have this issue on a Google test device (Pixel 2 - virtual with Android 9).

Comment: I have the same issue like @OvidiuUşvat

Comment: Also facing this issue - Pixel 2 and Nexus 5 are marked as the devices. Would be nice to even know how to catch this error and fail more gracefully if some devices are incapable of running flutter

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same issue.

The error came from Google Play automated tests. You can see it by looking at "Testing", "Pre-Launch Report", "Details" (see image).
[image: Google Play Pre-launch report details]

If you click on "Show more" button, and scroll down, it shows a Google Wear (virtual) device (x86). I am not targeting wear devices, so this seems to be a glitch with Google Play Store, which you can ignore (if this is your case).

[image: Google wear]

Comment: same here, the device name is Sdk_gwear_g3_x86

Comment: This has been resolved. I am not sure if the google Play Store fixed the issue or if the latest Flutter SDK 3.7.9 fixed it. In either case, my latest build passed google Play Test without any issues.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it's not happening for a wear device, but for a Pixel 2 (virtual device). Haven't found a solution yet :(

Comment: I have the same issue like @novas1r1

Comment: same here. @novas1r1

Comment: I have the same issue like @novas1r1

Comment: @novas1r1 how you solved this? I've exactly the same issue

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't solve it, the issue still persists :(

Comment: Same, error is shown by Play console, but it works normally on Emulator of same configuration, Pixel 2 Android 9 (SDK 28).

Answer (score -1):

**Generate the Signed APK or App Bundle without connecting any Android device or Emulator**

Follow the steps :

- Remove all device/phone/Emulator connection from Android Studio
- Add this to android/app level build.gradle file :

`defaultConfig { ndk { abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64" } }`

- Add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in `gradle.properties`
- Add your own signing config for the release build.
- Then generate signed apk or app bundle using android studio or `flutter build apk --release` or `flutter build appbundle --release`
- Use this new generated apk/appbundle in the release

Comment: that's working for me. : abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"

Comment: `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` has been deprecated since 2017 and is no longer used by gradle.

Comment: Why do you add `x86` to `abiFilters` if it's not supported by Flutter?

Comment: This does not explain why the crash happens or why these steps (if they do) prevent it from happening

Comment: This does not work for me.