# Flutter Google PlayStore publication fails with Pre-Launch Error

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, publish

I'm trying to publish my app on Google Play Store, but everytime i try, everytime i receive this error below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.domain.package_name/fr.domain.package_nam.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
```

I've tried to add the packagingOptions inside the build.gradle file but nothing change. I'm a little bit lost on this case.

```
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libapp.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libflutter.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libapp.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libflutter.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libapp.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so'
    }
```

Someone could help me on this please ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Well, short and sweet as we say. I've read a related bug and i think that it's my error too.

I've opened the section "See more" inside the test page and i've seen that te device is Google Wear. But my project is for a smartphone device, not a watch.

[Flutter app crashes on /lib/arm64 - couldn't find "libflutter.so"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75797853/flutter-app-crashes-on-lib-arm64-couldnt-find-libflutter-so?rq=2)

[image]