# Google Play Store & Flutter: couldn't find "libflutter.so" on Google Pixel 2 (virtual)

Tags: flutter, google-play, codemagic

I'm encountering an issue when publishing my application on the store, and I don't want to go through multiple releases to try all the solutions I've found on Stack Overflow.

Here's my error:

```
couldn't find "libflutter.so"
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 (Runtime.java:1012)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:1669)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary (FlutterJNI.java:141)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call (FlutterLoader.java:191)
  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call (FlutterLoader.java:184)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

From what I understand by reading the Stack Overflow posts, it seems like I should add the following to make it work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76292482/6401457

*We also can read comments in this posts, 3 peoples have the same problem with the same device*

I would like to understand why, especially after reading this: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle

I generate my releases using Codemagic, and I don't want to use credits for my tests.

Do you have a solution?

Thank you.